# Ansible: Get other number than the input out of a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a set of three numbers: 19, 20 and 21 and I need to get one of them except the one of the input. My approch is to use the jinja-difference filter, which works fine, but I don't know how I can replace the hardcoded number (in my example "19") with an variable (in my example "hostnumber") in the difference-filer.

Example:

`ansible-playbook get_other_host.yml -e "hostname=abcd0015"`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Extract the hostnumber
      set_fact:
        hostnumber: "{{ (hostname[6:] | int) + 4 }}"

# Output is: 19
    - name: The hostnumber is
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostnumber }}"

# Output is: 20 and 21
    - name: The other hosts are
      debug:
        msg: "{{ [19,20,21] | difference([19]) }}"

# Output is: 20 or 21
    - name: One other host is
      debug:
        msg: "{{ [19,20,21] | difference([19]) | random }}"
```

Comment: `msg: "{{ [19,20,21] | difference([hostnumber | int]) }}"` right?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes this works. Do you want to post an answer, so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 has access to all the vars, including the `hostnumber` that was previously set; it may already be an `int`, but using the `| int` on a variable that is already `int` is harmless

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ [19,20,21] | difference([hostnumber | int]) }}"
```